# how to combine 2 lists uniquely

Tags: python, list

I'm working with extremely long lists and am trying to come up with an iterative solution to combining the 2 lists in a unique way.

For example, I have lists

```
a = [TF1,Tar1]
b = [Tar1, TF1]
```

I want the following iterator (if possible) containing the tuples:

```
(TF1,Tar1)    
(TF1,TF1)  
(Tar1,Tar1)
```

This excludes (Tar1,TF1) because the opposite ordering has already been added.

My current approach is loop through each list and use a dictionary to keep track of what's been added. This is taking up a huge amount of RAM because list a is 12,000 long and list b is 15000 long. Making the resulting dictionary contain about a*b/2 entries which in this case is 90M entries.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for a list to have duplicate elements? e.g. a = [TF1, Tar1, TF1]

Comment: @Gargamel See his example.

Comment: I did, but it doesn't answer my question, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Does the order of the results matter?

Comment: Do you want an output of 2-tuples(pairs) or of greater length tuples? You said your lists were 12000 and 15000 long

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the problem arises with common elements between two lists. If you can segregate the cases of combining common and unique elements, you would solve your problem

i.e. you need to create the following Cartesian products

```
a_unique X b_unique
a_unique X b_common
a_common X b_unique
a_common X b_common
```

Of the four cases, the last one would pose a problem as it would create non-unique pairs. On a second thought, the last Cartesian with unique pairs is a simple selection of 2 elements from a_common.

Finally, segregating the elements can be done by creating a set and of both the lists and then iterating while comparing

```
>>> #Sample Lists
>>> a = ['C0','C1','C2','A0','A1','A2']
>>> b = ['C0','C1','C2','B0','B1','B2']
>>> from itertools import product, combinations, chain
>>> # Create sets for O(1) lookup
>>> a_key = set(a)
>>> b_key = set(b)
>>> # Segerate elements to unique and common for both lists
>>> a = {'common':a_key & b_key,
         'unique':a_key - common}
>>> b = {'common':a_key & b_key,
         'unique':b_key - common}
>>> # Create cartesian products forall the cases
>>> list(chain.from_iterable([product(a['unique'], b['unique']),
                      product(a['unique'], b['common']),
                      product(a['common'], b['unique']),
                      combinations(a['common'], 2)]))
[('A0', 'B0'), ('A0', 'B1'), ('A0', 'B2'), ('A1', 'B0'), ('A1', 'B1'), ('A1', 'B2'), ('A2', 'B0'), ('A2', 'B1'), ('A2', 'B2'), ('A0', 'C0'), ('A0', 'C1'), ('A0', 'C2'), ('A1', 'C0'), ('A1', 'C1'), ('A1', 'C2'), ('A2', 'C0'), ('A2', 'C1'), ('A2', 'C2'), ('C0', 'B0'), ('C0', 'B1'), ('C0', 'B2'), ('C1', 'B0'), ('C1', 'B1'), ('C1', 'B2'), ('C2', 'B0'), ('C2', 'B1'), ('C2', 'B2'), ('C0', 'C1'), ('C0', 'C2'), ('C1', 'C2')]
```

Comment: You can find your common and unique sets more easily using set operations: `common = a_key & b_key; a_unique = a_key - common; b_unique = b_key - common`. Other than that, this is a great answer, as it will never use more than `O(M+N)` storage, even if `a` and `b` are the same list (so that every yielded value from `itertools.product` would also appear reversed).

Comment: @Totem: I think the title says it all `how to combine 2 lists uniquely`

Comment: I think your use of dicts here is a bit strange. You don't need `a['common']` or `b['common']`; just use `common`. Also, You should write `common = a_key & b_key`; it's undefined currently. There's also no reason to use `.from_iterable`; just use `chain` and don't make a list. To write it out: `a_key = set(a); b_key = set(b); common = a_key & b_key; a_only = a_key - common; b_only = b_key - common; list(chain(product(a_only, b_only), product(a_only, common), product(common, b_only), combinations(common, 2)))`. Good idea though, I wouldn't have thought of it.

Answer (score 1):

To generate the pairs iteratively, you'll want to look at the [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function:

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = [1, 3, 7]
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product(l1, l2))
[(1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 7), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 7), (3, 1), (3, 3), (3, 7)]
```

However, I don't think it's possible to remove duplicate pairs without keeping track of the ones you've already seen.

To remove duplicates in-memory, I would sort the tuples and make it a set:

```
>>> pairs = list(itertools.product(l1, l2))
>>> set(map(tuple, map(sorted, pairs)))
set([(1, 2), (2, 7), (1, 3), (3, 3), (2, 3), (1, 7), (3, 7), (1, 1)])
```

If you want to keep memory low and you can use the disk, I would suggest using a merge sort backed by disk files similar to [this approach](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/sorting-million-32-bit-integers-in-2mb.html). When iterating through the result of `itertools.product`, sort the pair and write it to disk. Then use the merge sort and read the sorted list, removing duplicates (since they will be adjacent).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can avoid duplicates without storing *all* the values you've generated so far. Instead, you want to check to see which values that you generate will later be generated in reverse, and only keep track of those items. If you don't have a huge number of collisions, this will require substantially less memory (though it's still `O(M*N)` in the worst case).

Here's how I'd do it:

```
import itertools

def product_without_reversed_duplicates(a, b):
    a_set = set(a)
    b_set = set(b)
    dupes = set()

    for x, y in itertools.product(a, b):
        if (x, y) not in dupes: # take (x, y) only if it is not a dupe of a previous item
            yield x, y
            if x in b_set and y in a_set:  # test if (y, x) will be generated later
                dupes.add((y, x))          # if so, add it to the set to be skipped
```

Note that this assumes that `a` and `b` do not have any internal duplicates, and that you want to preserve the order of the product as much as possible (only skipping the reversed pairs). If duplicates within `a` or `b` are possible, you'll want to iterate on `itertools.product(a_set, b_set)` instead of what I have above. This however will give you results in an arbitrary order. You could work around that with extra steps to dedupe `a` and `b` while keeping their order, but I'll leave it to you to figure out the code for that, if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather tricky but here's a way to do it, with `O(n)` additional memory.

```
xs = ['a', 'b', 'd']
ys = ['b', 'a', 'c']

def unique(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [ x for x in seq if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]

xs = unique(xs)
ys = unique(ys)

x_added = set()
for x in xs:
    for y in ys:
        if y in x_added and x in set(ys):
            continue
        print(x, y)
    x_added.add(x)
```

Output:

```
a b
a a
a c
b b
b c
d b
d a
d c
```

Basically, we know a pair is already yielded, if `y` is already in one of the `x`s yielded so far, and `x` is one of the `ys`, since we have already iterated all `y`s for previous `x`s. The unique requirement just makes handling special cases easier.